Tengo un problema javax.imageio.IIOException ¿Como puedo agregar una imagen en un JPanel?
**Hola buenas, queria poner una imagen jpeg en un JPanel. Me sale una excepcion LA EXCEPCION ES : javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! nose que hice mal inserto el codido: **
package vistas;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelFondo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage bufferImage;
    private File archivo= new File("imagenes/Supermarket Amigable.jpeg");
    public PanelFondo() {
        
        try {
             System.out.println("Ruta: " + archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Puede leer: " + archivo.canRead());
                System.out.println("Puede escribir: " + archivo.canWrite());
                System.out.println("Puede ejecutar: " + archivo.canExecute());
            bufferImage = ImageIO.read(archivo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("LA EXCEPCION ES : "+e.toString());
        }
        
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {
        
        if(bufferImage != null) {
            grafico.drawImage(bufferImage, 0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight(), this);
        }
        super.paintComponent(grafico);
    }

}

**la distribucion de los paquetes es:  imagenes (donde estan las imagenes), main, vistas(se encuentra el JFrame y el JPanel). Todos los System.out.print del jpanel salen falsos, verifique los permisos y dan permiso de lectura y escritura ¿Como puedo resolver esto?
verifique la ruta y no era el problema, tambien verifique los permisos y todos estaban activos, tampoco era el problema.**
StackTrace
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
    at vistas.PanelFondo.<init>(PanelFondo.java:25)
    at vistas.VentanaPrueba.<init>(VentanaPrueba.java:14)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:10)


Añade el stacktrace a la pregunta

esto me aparece en el stacktrace      javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
at vistas.PanelFondo.(PanelFondo.java:25)
at vistas.VentanaPrueba.(VentanaPrueba.java:14)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Hola kmp, llego tarde... prueba con private File archivo= new File( "src/imagenes/Supermarket Amigable.jpeg" );.

eso tambien lo intente, pero ya lo solucione utilize ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/Supermarket Amigable.jpeg"));  y funciono gracias por tu ayuda
